# Content box resize with browser size

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out for hourssssssss how this website does this. If you go to [] and resize your browser screen, you'll see that the main content container in the middle gets smaller as your browser size gets smaller. How does it work?

I'm trying to do something similar with a wordpress website I am building.

Thank you,
AJ

Comment: It looks like javascript is involved.  Inspect the `#djslider92` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the stacked elements in the main column have a width of 65%, which refers to a proportion of their parent element. In this case, that's the entire width of the viewport. They'll resize to their min-width, which is set to 700px, and also their max-width, which is at 1920px. Pretty straight-forward CSS.

Get familiar with Firebug and/or Chrome and Safari's developer toolbars. They're indispensable for anyone working with websites.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to it being Responsive. It likely uses CSS @media queries to change the sites width depending on the resolution of the browser.

You can find more information here: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Also, your site is not a great example of it, see better examples here:
http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: That site isn't responsive. It's merely fluid.

Comment: -1 as it isn't responsive. +1 for suggesting and sharing information regarding media queries.